# Delete this post for me

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Role-playing Games Stack Exchange post: [What is 5e's Damage Dice Progression?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130887/what-is-5es-damage-dice-progression)

I am removing the Question for a lack of valid input in an attempt to clean up spam and trolling. Delete it, as it refuses to allow me to do so.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83191/discussion-on-question-by-blue-shocker-64-delete-this-post-for-me).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I deleted the question in... question.

Sorry, I didn’t even see this meta before I did it, I was just responding to multiple flags on the Q and mod message discussion.  But the question(s) were a mess of many iterations of edit by many people, hostile discussion and argument, ending in the OP’s suspension. There was little there of value to anyone.

While the other answers are correct in that we are under no obligation to delete content just because the OP wants us to, I feel that often on this site we go way too far trying to “save” some question that has clearly become cancerous way beyond a valuable use of our time.  When it’s causing continued problems, we need to stop “picking at the scab.”  The community should delete the question, if it's really bad the mods should suspend/mod message anyone that needs it, and then we should all move on to spending our effort on the hundreds of other constructive questions from users respecting the site and wanting our help.

We like good questions and we like good users.  We should try to provide guidance to improve ones not so good yet.  But when that help is resisted and it’s not going to be a good investment, it is time for us to clean the slate.

If my fellow mods disagree we can undelete it, but that just brings back argument and wasted work for content that is not helping the OP and not really helping anyone else much either, can’t be meaningfully refined, never get an accepted answer, etc., and I think it would be imprudent. If someone has a good on topic question on this subject I would much rather them post it in the future instead of being referred to a previous bag of burning hair as a "duplicate."

Comment: I think this was for the best and support having done that.

Answer (score 11):

## We do not delete questions on request

When you submit material to the site you grant the site an [irrevocable license to use the material, forever](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). We do not remove material on request, and especially not when others have put work into submitting their own material as answers.

Your question currently does not meet our rules for being deleted, and so it will remain.

## Editing is not optional

This license also grants others (i.e., us) permission to edit your material to follow out content rules.

This site is designed from the ground up to be edited. As the help page [“Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?”](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/editing) says (emphasis mine),

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. **If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.**

If you do not ever want your questions edited, don’t post them on this site.

## You may request to have your identity removed from the question

The license also guarantees you the right to disavow any relationship to the material we have a license to use. You may request your account be dissociation from a post, without any need to justify it.

For detailed instructions about account dissociation, please see [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA 3.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0)

## Reposting a new question is fine

You were asked to post your other question in its own question post. Doing that is a good idea.

## Reposting the same question is a bad idea

Reposting the same question to avoid content rules and editing will result in the reposted question being closed.

Repeated reposting can result in account privileges being temporarily suspended.

Comment: says the guy who spammed edits to alter my question, as well as locked the question because I was incapable of taking the discussion to the Chat.

Comment: @BlueShocker64 Getting into a wrestling match here is not going to end well.  Please let it go, we are trying to help within the constraints of how this SE site works.

Comment: then he should stop altering my Question. He did not just edit my post, but actually (repeatedly) changed what was being asked.

Comment: @BlueShocker64 The community edits are almost entirely improving the clarity and formatting of the question. The tag edits were done according to the meaning of tags on the site. As far as I can see none of the edits significantly change the actual question being asked. And above all, edits are not optional and edit warring gets questions locked.

Comment: @SirCinnamon then you are free to remove the question. The edits that were made did in fact alter the directive of the question asked, I had to change it to correct the course of the question at hand back to the original.

Comment: @BlueShocker64 That is not how this site works. May I suggest that this site probably does not suit your purposes. You haven’t once responded to teaching about how to use the site without arguing. This is a strong sign that you do not like how things are done here and should go somewhere you like better. This site will not change to suit your tastes. We are not interested in having users who are not interested in using the site as it is designed to be used.

Comment: it should be designed with the person who comes along in search of information in mind as much as it should be designed for the people who answer the questions.

Comment: @BlueShocker64 It is. But you’ve refused to use the avenues the site provides, and refused to respect others’ knowledge of how to manage the site. You have two options: stop arguing long enough to learn how to get your question answered in our **collaborative** system, or stop using the site. Those are the only options. If you try to pick something that is not one of those options, we can pick for you and get on with our business. The amount of disruption you have visited upon the site is already excessive for one person.

Comment: and yet, we wouldn't even be discussing this had I been allowed to simply delete the question.

Comment: That’s enough arguing.

Comment: Thanks for giving us enough time to try.  Interestingly, David C has come up with something quite interesting as a side effect of this discussion, but he was unable to post it as an answer since we could never get the querent to work with us to get the question reopened.

Answer (score 7):

I don't usually like to vote to delete content that could be helpful to other users. The reason you can't delete the question yourself is because of the answers to the question. Clearly, enough users thought it was helpful enough to answer (and upvote those answers) so in order for it to be deleted, a number of the site's trusted users or a mod would have to intervene.

While the site is certainly designed for direct questions and answers for users, it is also useful as a database of information for people to access. The question you asked is one that may come up for a number of people and as such is a very useful question (I upvoted it for that reason). You also had accepted [one of the answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130889/41726), which I agree is a good summary of how damage dice works for monsters, but as the answer states, what you are searching for in a "comprehensive list" does not exist:

> There isn't a progression for PCs.

If there was a more comprehensive table, one of the 5th edition experts would have included it in an answer. Instead you were given one answer with all of the official tables (the only one I know of is the monster size table) and [another useful answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130890/41726) with some commonalities for weapon damages.

When you re-asked the question for more information, the only real answer that could be given is "there isn't anything else, look back at the other question" which is why we marked it as a duplicate. When other users would have arrived at the "comprehensive list question", they would have seen that all the information the 5e experts on this site has was already cataloged in the previous post.

If you think that the question could use more answers, hang around the site some, ask some good questions, maybe even post some answers, and when you have enough [reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can [add a bounty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to your question in the hopes that someone else finds it to add another answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83192/discussion-on-answer-by-david-coffron-delete-this-post-for-me).

Comment: Did we ever end up with a question where your work on that google docs got fitted into an answer? I am moved to ask one so that we can benefit from your analysis being captured in our libraryh of good answers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Potential X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and setting expectations

You may be looking at an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but I'm not sure that's the case.

Understanding *why* you are looking for this list may be a better way for the site to focus on helping you write a question that's useful for yourself AND for others.

### Asking for a developing specific item

If you have a specific item you're trying to stat, I'd suggest starting with asking how to stat that. It may be easier than you're making it out to be.

### Asking for a list compilation

But I can also see the case where you're just wanting a compilation of lists. That is a valid question, but it may receive downvotes as showing poor effort. The stack generally doesn't respond well to "do my work for me", even if you have tried incredibly hard to do it first. Please don't take the downvotes personally if they do come, the goal is to get you answer that useful for you and hopefully others. If you get downvotes and you get an answer that helps, that's still a win.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83193/discussion-on-answer-by-nautarch-delete-this-post-for-me).